# Using WMASFWriter generates a video which pauses at each keyframe interval

Tags: directshow, wmv, keyframe

I am attempting to create a DirectShow source filter based on the pushsource example from the DirectShow SDK. My source filter essentially outputs a set of bitmaps, each of which typically lasts around 600 milliseconds, to a video. I have set up a filter graph which uses Async_reader with a Wave Parser for audio and my new filter to push the video (the filter is a CSourceStream and I populate my frames in the FillBuffer function). These are both connected to a WMASFWriter to output a WMV.

What I am finding is that at times corresponding the keyframe interval the video pauses for a second or two. This seems to be worse at HD resolutions, thought that could be a red herring. What kinds of things might be causing this? Is it related to how often I allow FillBuffer to be called (my frame rate is 30fps, so I end up with the same bitmap being repeated for several frames)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common sense (as opposed to specific experience with effect in question) suggests that encoding of a key frame consumes too much of bandwidth, and the remainder is insufficient to encode movement of the segment which immediately follows the key frame. I assume this is CBR mode, and perhaps VBR mode could give a better encoding.

Comment: I am indeed using a CBR profile - currently the bitrate is only 100kbps. I guess that's probably pretty low for 1080p (especially after looking at the profiles in Windows Live Movie Maker)? After some initial experimentation, raising the bitrate to 1000kbps seemed to help the problem quite a bit so I suspect I need to hit on a configuration that works well.

Comment: So that was it, encoding with extremely low bitrate CBR profile, encoder has no way to further degrade quality, and it started dropping frames instead.

Comment: Yes, I am now investigating my profile settings. What kind of bitrate would you suggest for a CBR profile?

Comment: Check this out "Suggested VC1 WMV Bitrates": http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/encoder/thread/9e99cde9-c3c7-4ee9-89cc-ae718873357a